# MySQL Trigger to compare 2 values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am new in MySQL.

I want to create a trigger that compares the cost in the tender table with the tender_request table, if the cost in the tender table is bigger than the cost in the tender_request table will give a static score in the KPI table.

tender table (ID, Name, cost)

tender_request table(ID, Name, Estimated_cost, supplier_ID, tenderID)

KPI table(ID, cost)

supplier_performance(KPI_ID, tender_ID,tender_request_ID)

I get the following error when I insert a row in request table:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'tender_request.TenderID' in 'where clause'
```

How can I correct the syntax error?

```
BEGIN
SET  @Ecost=(SELECT `estimated_cost` FROM tender where `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`);

SET  @cost=(SELECT `cost` FROM tender_request where `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`);


IF(@Ecost>@cost)  then
 UPDATE `kpi` set kpi.Cost=10 WHERE `kpi`.KPI_ID=`supplier performance`.KPIID 
and `supplier performance`.TenderID=tender.Tender_ID ;
     END IF;
    END
```

Comment: I always expect to see NEW. and/or OLD. Variables in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  query based on two table you should use a join  eg:

```
  SELECT `estimated_cost` 
  FROM tender
  INNER JOIN tender_request ON `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`
```

or

```
  SELECT `cost` 
  FROM tender_request 
  INNER JOIN tender ON  `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.TenderID
```

Comment: I get the following error
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: removed  query that return  2  column  .. was only a suggetion that can't be assigned  to a single var ...  anyway your problem is related  to the missing join in select as in both the query above

Comment: I still get an error in insert a new row in tender_request table                           #1109 - Unknown table 'tender_request' in field list

Comment: I am trying to insert in tender_request table                                       
`INSERT INTO  tender_request (Tender_Request_ID, Cost, Document, Status, supplierID, TenderID) VALUES (112,900,Null,Active,123,652)`

Comment: I can only  .. see the code you posted .. and the code you have in comment is not related  to the trigger and the error you posted  in your Original 
 Question.  at a first look you have in your schema tender_request  table with column ID and not  Tender_Request_ID column  ..

Comment: I am trying to insert a row in the tender_request table after applying the trigger on it, but it shows me an error  ` #1109 - Unknown table 'tender_request' in field list`

Comment: this mean thatb my answer is right and you hould post a nwe question for the new error